# How to send a POST Request to Octoprint in Java?

Tags: java, json, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, octoprint

I want to send a POST Request to the Octoprint API via the Apache HttpClient, something like shown here: http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/api/job.html#issue-a-job-command (e.g. to start a job). I've read the docs of both, but still getting "Bad Request" as answer.

Tried several other Post Request, but never getting something else. Guess I'm writing the request wrong somehow.

```java
CloseableHttpClient posterClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:5000/api/job");
        post.setHeader("Host", "http://localhost:5000");
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        post.setHeader("X-Api-Key", "020368233D624EEE8029991AE80A729B");

        List<NameValuePair> content = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        content.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command", "start"));



        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(content));
        CloseableHttpResponse answer = posterClient.execute(post);

        System.out.println(answer.getStatusLine());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the content type is wrong. As per documentation [here](http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/api/general.html), expect bodies to be in JSON formart. Your code on the other hand uses application/x-www-form-urlencoded as per this piece of code `post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(content));`

Quick fix, make the below changes and try it out:

```
    String json= "{\"command\":\"start\"}";
    
    //This will change change you BasicNameValuePair to an Entity with the correct Content Type
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    //Now you just set it to the body of your post
    post.setEntity(entity);
```

You will likely want to review how you create the content of your post. The above is just so you check if the issue is indeed related to the content type.

Let us know of the outcome.

Comment: Add this line after entity declaration: `entity.setContentEncoding("application/json");` if it still doesn't work, I will take a second look on the docs again.

Comment: Jep, still doesn't work... looks like that now:

content.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command", "start"));


  StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(content.toString(),ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  entity.setContentEncoding("application/json");

  
  post.setEntity(entity);

  CloseableHttpResponse answer = posterClient.execute(post);

Comment: OK, in won't work likely because of how we are trying to create the json. Your `content` variable prints as `[command=start]` and that is indeed wrong. You can view it by using `System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));`. You will need to create your JSON using a library for that. Which json library you have on your project?

Comment: Im using Jackson, but if you can suggest a better one, feel free. Don't have much knowledge anyway and haven't written much JSON-code yet  in this project.

Comment: Since we are just trying... take a look at the updated code, I wrote a json manually. Not really a long term solution, but it will tell us if we are going the right way. Try it and let me know if the error persists.

Comment: Works now! Getting back the expected "204 NO CONTENT". Thank you very much!